# How to delete multiple records in webgrid without refreshing whole page in MVC? Only Webgrid should refresh

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I am making Some functionalities in my webgrid. When I select one or more than one checkbox to delete the data my page get refreshed.I wanted to have functionality in which My webgrid should refresh not all the webpage. Please  help me guys.An link or any tutorial will seriously help me.

Answer (score 0):

your questions is not very clear but it sounds like you require a jQuery AJAX request.

AJAX is the art of exchanging data with a server, and update parts of a web page - without reloading the whole page.

This is a short example from http://www.w3schools.com/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

You will need to use AJAX to update that particular part of your webpage without refreshing your whole page. For further reading on AJAX please check https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/.